# RecyclerView child with same height

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I want to add a spinning logo with some text at the center of recyclerview while my data is being loaded. How can i set the item height equal to recyclerView height, like fill_parent?

Answer (score 1):

Try something like:

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <RecyclerView
        ... />

    <!-- This is the view you will use to show the loading message -->
    <View 
        android:id="@+id/loading_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" 
        .... />
```

Then just toggle the visibility of `loading_view` accordingly.

Comment: Fine, will do so. Thought of a adapter way to do that though.